# Inline paste from System Clipboard

Tags: cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard, paste

I have recently started using Neovim on Windows 10. I use `"+p` to paste from the system clipboard. But sometimes I just want to paste inline before or after the cursor without adding a new line. Need an elegant solution to do the same.

It is preferable if there is no third-party dependency and the keyboard combo works on any platform (Win/Mac/Linux).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal "put" does not add a newline of its own. If you get it then you've yanked it earlier.

Actually, it's not too hard to trim stuff from the register, it's rather a problem of "another unneeded mapping(s)". So I'd rather suggest you to re-think your copy process, not to re-design paste process, as this:

```
"=trim(@+)<Enter>p
```

Comment: Actually I have started using Neovim in vscode through vim extension since a week, and I have grown fond of the vim way of doing things.I tried in neovim natively and it works fine. I will consider as a true answer. I may use neovim natively from now on.