# Pasting from system clipboard adds an unwanted new line

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, microsoft-windows, os-clipboard

On windows, using neovim, with `clipboard=unnamedplus` , when I paste from the system clipboard using `p` or `:put` , it will always paste in a newline , even if the content of the clipboard has no newline. (This issue happens in windows terminal and powershell or when using neovide as a gui app)

If I copy the content of my clipboard to notepad , it will just paste everything on the same line , so clearly there isn't a newline character inside my clipboard, but in nvim , it creates a new line and then pastes the content of the clipboard on that new line.

If I disable `clipboard=unnamedplus` , I get the behaviour I want when pasting something I yanked from inside neovim, but when I try pasting something from the system clipboard using `"+p` , it still gets pasted on a newline , even if there are no new line characters in my clipboard.

What am I missing? What I want is for pasting from the system clipboard to behave the same as if it was yanked from inside vim.

I've seen this question which is somewhat similar [Inline paste from System Clipboard](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/inline-paste-from-system-clipboard) and the suggestion is to use a different mapping that trims the clipboard but I don't want a new mapping I just want to press `p` and not have some new line added to the clipboard that doesn't exist otherwise. If it's not possible I'd like to at least understand why neovim adds a new line here.

Answer (score 0):

**I have some updates at the end, this is very inconsistent in vim**

It is due to the way you copied in Windows.

Open notepad, and type this:

```
123
12345
12345123456789

000
00000
000000000
```

Then keep the cursor on line 1, press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, until you
get to line 5. Copy the text. It will be moved to Vim in **line type**, which we
can see with `:reg` like this:

```
Type Name Content
  l  "*   ^J123^J12345^J12345123456789^J^J
```

The `l` indicates line type, and with `p`, `P`, or `:put`, Vim will paste with
newlines. Rather, Vim will move to a newline and then paste.

Now, back to notepad. Put the cursor on line 6, press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>,
until you get to end of line 8. Copy the text. It will be moved to Vim in
**character type**, which we can see with `:reg` like this:

```
Type Name Content
  c  "*   000^J00000^J000000000
```

The `c` indicates character type, and with `p`, `P`, or `:put`, Vim will paste
without newlines. Rather, Vim will paste on the current line with the cursor.

With using mouse to select in notepad, I think, the type is character when last
newline is not selected. When newline is selected, the type is line. It also
varies within Vim, when the clipboard content is unchanged though the type is
changed. It is inconsistent there.

Every time I check and recheck, I get different result in Vim, which seems to be
inconsistent. Currently, I think, Vim uses the last character in the system
clipboard to decide whether the type is line or character. If selecting single
line or multiple lines with keyboard, with no terminal newline, then Vim makes
it type `c`. If selecting single line or multiple lines with keyboard, with a
terminal newline, then Vim makes it type `l`. Based on that, Vim will either
paste on current line or paste on new line. This inconsistency issue will not
occur when yanking within Vim, where Vim is aware about yanking characters or
lines. When using system clipboard, there is **no easy way to consistently**
make it type `l` or type `c`.

Comment: The **Best work-around** ( always works ! ) is this : while in insert mode , move the cursor to the Point where you want to paste , then type `ctrl-r` , then `shift-8` , `vim` will paste your text right there , with no extra newlines , no matter whether that is type c or type l.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately `ctrl-r` + `shift-8` still pastes with new lines. The `:reg` command is useful to know, I was not aware of it. I've tried multiple ways of copying from windows and no matter what I do, including the way you mentioned I still get line types in my register. I also have this issue when yanking directly from vim when using `clipboard=unamedplus` but I don't have this issue when I disable this option. What I can only assume is that windows is doing something to the clipboard and vim isn't handling it correctly.

Comment: So, I've done a bit more investigation. When using vim pasting works perfectly between windows and vim. The issue only happens to me when using neovim even with a clean config. At this point it might be a bug in neovim and not just me doing something wrong.

Comment: (A) When you did `ctrl-r` + `*` & got the newline , was the text already ending in newline ? (B) If YES : It is Working Correctly : you got the text which was copied , including the newline. (C) If NO : It is a Definite Bug in `vim` or `neovim` : I too got that inconsistency. (D) Basic Core is that `vim` has no way to know whether that is `l` or `c` , hence it might be using vague heuristics !

Comment: I managed to track down the issue. It was a bug in neovim that has now been fixed. It works like I would expect when using the latest pre-release of neovim 0.10

Here's the link to the PR that appears to have fixed my issue https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/22566